# ¿A qué se refiere Android Studio con el alert 'Typo: in word'?

Tags: java, android-studio

Android Studio me está lanzando una alerta en una variable que tengo declarada de la siguiente forma:

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
```

La alerta, dice lo siguiente:

*Spellchecker inspection helps locate typos and misspelling in your code, comments and literals, and fix them in one click.*

Si comprendo que me ayuda a corregir errores de escritura pero... ¿qué error de escritura tengo en esa variable declarada? ¿Es porque incluye el nombre 'firebase' dentro?

Comment: Significa que esa palabra no está en el diccionario. ¿Llegaste a usar procesadores como Microsoft Word, recuerdas que ponían una especia de subrayado ondulado en rojo debajo de las palabras con error? Aquí ocurre algo parecido. Eso no provocará ningún error en tu código. Puedes hacer varias cosas: agregar la palabra al diccionario, desactivar Spellchecker (sopesa bien esa decisión, no la tomes a la ligera), o ignorar las alertas. [SpellChecker es un framework de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework). Intuyo que sirve p. e. para documentar código.

Comment: Sebastian revisa la respuesta de A.Cedano explica lo que preguntas en tu respuesta, en realidad no es un error es simplemente un aviso. @SebastianPaduano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La traducción literal del mensaje:

> Spellchecker inspection helps locate typos and misspelling in your
>   code, comments and literals, and fix them in one click.

Es la siguiente:

> La inspección del corrector ortográfico ayuda a localizar errores
>   tipográficos y errores ortográficos en su código, comentarios y
>   literales, y a corregirlos con un solo clic.

Cuando aparece sobre una palabra no hay que alarmarse. Significa que esa palabra no está en el diccionario.

¿Llegaste a usar procesadores como Microsoft Word, recuerdas que ponían una especie de subrayado ondulado en rojo debajo de las palabras con error? Aquí ocurre algo parecido. Claro, en un procesador de texto eso es gravísimo, pero no en un editor de código (no al menos en cuanto a funcionamiento del programa). Eso no provocará ningún error en tu código.

Puedes hacer varias cosas:

- agregar la palabra al diccionario,
- desactivar SpellChecker
- o ignorar las alertas (tampoco son tan llamativas como las alertas de código erróneo).

Sopesa bien la decisión que tomes, sobre todo si te decides por la primera o la segunda. Si no piensas usar el diccionario, no agregues palabras a él tan solo para que Android Studio no te moleste con esa advertencia; si piensas usar el diccionario, no desactives SpellChecker...

SpellChecker es un framework de Android. Intuyo que sirve p. e. para documentar código. En este enlace ellos explican en qué consiste este framework y explican cómo funciona. Quizá leyéndolo completo puedas decidir lo que debes hacer en este caso.

Ellos lo introducen diciendo esto:

> La plataforma Android ofrece un marco de corrector ortográfico que le
>   permite implementar y acceder a la corrección ortográfica en su
>   aplicación. El marco es una de las API de servicios de texto que
>   ofrece la plataforma Android.
>
> Para usar el marco en su aplicación, cree un tipo especial de servicio
>   de Android que genere un objeto de sesión del corrector ortográfico.
>   En función del texto que proporcione, el objeto de sesión devuelve
>   sugerencias de ortografía generadas por el corrector ortográfico.
>
> <sub>▸  [Spell checker framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework) en la documentación de Android</sub>